Interpretation of "by 2028（a time period）"

Meanwhile, there is a looming shortage of training data. By one estimate, the stock of high-quality textual data on the internet will have run out by 2028.

Ii is talking about the training of AI models.  Which of the following does by 2028 mean exactly:

by 2028.1.1
by 2028.12.31
by a unspecified time in 2028


Or (4) By that year. In other words, the focus is on the year, not a more precise time frame within the year. Grammatically they are all possible, but I would interpret the number 2028 as implying a certain vagueness. Like saying there were 30,000 people at the football match. The whole point is that we are making an estimate, not a precise prophecy.

If I were the mayor, and I had promised to fix the town sewers 'by 2024', and they were not repaired on 1.1.2024, my enemies (or my rival in the next election) might say, 'they're still broken', and if the job was finally finished at 23:50 on 31.12.2024, I would say 'Look, folks, I did it!'.

This question is similar to: What does "by" mean if we are talking about a date?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You forgot to include 3:14pm on 7 September 2028.

And "none of the above".

None of the above.
It's like saying:

This car is a gas hog. At this rate we're going to run out of gas by Ohio.

It's a very rough estimate. If the car runs out of gas leaving Ohio and entering Kentucky, the person could say "See? I told you."
When predicting something that is distant in time or space, in an ever-changing context without precise real-time measurements, the phrase is "seat of the pants" and has no precise meaning, not even "at some point in 2028".

I don't agree with  "and has no precise meaning, not even "at some point in 2028". It is confusing.

Read the entire paragraph instead of focusing, like AI, on parts of it.

TImR: 1 James Mathai: 0

OP has asked about the meaning of “by” in the sentence:

Meanwhile, there is a looming shortage of training data. By one estimate, the stock of high-quality textual data on the internet will have run out by 2028.

The sentence provides an estimated time frame (not an exact date). The following definition of “by” from the Cambridge Dictionary applies:

by preposition (Not Later Than).
not later than; at or before:

She had promised to be back by five o'clock.
The application must be in by the 31st to be accepted.
By the time I got to the station the train had already gone.


Please note::

“By” sets a deadline or boundary, indicating the latest possible time for an event.
"Not later than” accurately describes its meaning in this context.
Application to the stock of high-quality textual data: The data shortage could happen anytime up to and including 2028, aligning with the “not later than” interpretation.

The correct answer is not there among the given choices. Option 3 has to be modified
4) by an unspecified time on or before 2028.

I think you've understood this question about as well as AI understands most things.

@TimR Does your AI refer a dictionary and give the answer???

The OP is not askng about the meaning of "by" but about the meaning of "by 2028".

@TimR Is 2028 a word? If you didn't understand the last sentence indicates what is meant "by 2028."
